# WCF - Return additional values

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, wcf, silverlight

I have some WCF-Services in my Project which are looking like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    public int[] GetCalculatedValues()
    {
        //....
    }
```

What I want now is to return from 'each' service-method common datas like this example:

- In the above method I update some DatabaseObjects. Now I want to return the table name and the id of the entities wich was update.
- Custom state values of the Server (we can set a flag to the Server for shut down in specific time, and this value we want to tell the Client by each Server call).

Is there a way so solve that without using the return value?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't refactor your method to return an object with multiple properties?

Comment: This is possible but the best way would be to return a generic class here. The prolbem is that I think generic classes are not well supported in WCF-Framework, or not?